# Avoid MongoDB read skew in reactive transactions with Spring?

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, transactions, reactive-programming, spring-data-mongodb

I'm using MongoDB 4.2 with Spring Boot 2.3.1 and I'm looking for a way to avoid read skew in my scenario.

I have a collection named "metadata" and one named "messages". The latter contains messages like this:

```
{
  "aggregateId" : "myAggregateId",
  "messageId" : "uuid", 
  "message" : "some message"
}
```

and "metadata" contains the version for each "aggregate":

```
{
  "aggregateId" : "myAggregateId",
  "version" : NumberLong(40)
}
```

The reason for not just storing messages in a subarray is among other things that the number of messages per aggregate can be greater than 16Mb (which is the document limit in MongoDB).

When issuing a query I *think* I'd like to create an interface like this for the users:

```java
public interface MyRepository {
     Mono<Aggregate> findByAggregateId(String aggregateId);
}
```

where `Aggregate` is defined like this:

```
public class Aggregate {
    private final String aggregateId;
    private final int version;
    private Flux<Message> messages;
}
```

The problem now is that I'd like `Aggregate` to be consistent when reading! I.e. if there are writes to the same aggregate *before* `messages` are subscribed to then I *don't* want the new messages to be included (those written after I've subscribed to `Mono<Aggregate>`).

Let's look at an example. This is one attempt at an implementation:

```
public Mono<Aggregate> findByAggregateId(String aggregateId) {
    return transactionalOperator.execute(status -> 
        reactiveMongoTemplate.findOne(query(where("aggregateId").is(aggregateId)), Document.class, "metadata")
                             .map(metadata -> {
                                Aggregate aggregate = new Aggregate(metadata.getString("aggregateId"), metadata.getLong("version"));
                                Flux<Message> messages = reactiveMongoTemplate.find(query, Message.class, "messages");
                                aggregate.setMessages(messages);
                                return aggregate;
                             })
    );
}
```

I totally understand that this won't work since the `messages` `Flux` is not subscribed to in the transaction. But I can't figure out how I should combine the outer `Aggregate` that is a `Mono` and an inner `Flux` (messages) and retain the non-blocking capabilities AND consistency (i.e. avoid read skew)?

One approach would be to change the `Aggregate` class to this:

```
public class Aggregate {
    private final String aggregateId;
    private final int version;
    private Stream<Message> messages;
}
```

and change the `findByAggregateId` implementation to this:

```
public Mono<Aggregate> findByAggregateId(String aggregateId) {
    return transactionalOperator.execute(status -> 
        reactiveMongoTemplate.findOne(query(where("aggregateId").is(aggregateId)), Document.class, "metadata")
                             .flatMap(metadata -> {
                                Aggregate aggregate = new Aggregate(metadata.getString("aggregateId"), metadata.getLong("version"));
                                Stream<Message> messages = reactiveMongoTemplate.find(query, Message.class, "messages").toStream();
                                aggregate.setMessages(messages);
                                return aggregate;
                             })
    );
}
```

but calling `toStream` is a blocking operation so this is not right.

So what is the correct way to deal with this?

Comment: Use a transaction & snapshot read concern?

Comment: I am using a transaction here.

Comment: Sounds like you are halfway where you need to be.

Comment: Sure if a transaction is called around "findByAggregateId" and reading the "messages" then I suppose it would work. Maybe this is the way to go..

Comment: My understanding is you'll need to commit also.